What settings would block python from receiving socket data?
I'm on old ubuntu 18 systems that I did not setup.  Firewall is disabled
I'm running Python 2.7.17.
Running as an unprivileged user the following python code:
import socket

def start_server(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)
    print(f"Listening on {host}:{port}")

    while True:

        c, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {addr}")

        data = c.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            break

......

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 12345
    start_server(host, port)


I get no errors, it binds.  From another computer nmap shows the port open as well.  However if I try sending data to it, nothing is received. I don't get the "Connection from" message. The same code on another system works fine.  However if I run the code as root, I do receive data.  I'm using port 12345 (above the 1024 limit on the system).  I tried iperf (non-root) and it can receive in port 12345.  (I've tried other ports too with this).
Since it works as root, I don't think it is an external network issue.  Since iperf works, I think the issue might be specific to python.  Eventhough the exact same code works on another computer with the same python.
Are there any security settings either in python or OS that might give this type of behaviour?
Typically I'd attribute something like this to a firewall issue, outside network issue, or conflict but I've ruled that out.  I've never had a issue where it works with root but not a regular user (using ports over 1024).  And it does bind, it just that nothing makes it through.

port should be an integer, not a string. I get an error with port = "12345"

How do you know nothing is being received? You never print data.

Are you getting the "Connection from" message?

Sorry, I hand typed the code, its an integer in my code.  I am printing data in the "...." section.  It does alot with the data so I didn't think that section was relevant because I never get to the "Connection from" line.  (unless I'm root or running on another computer).  Updated orig post.

Did you try running unbuffered with python -u YOURSCRIPT.PY?

If you use netstat -anp | grep 12345 do you see your python process listening on the port? Are there other listeners? My suspicion is there's a process bound to a specific IP, which takes precedence over 0.0.0.0.

@MarkSetchell Why would that make a difference, unless the output is being written to a file/pipe?

@Barmar Maybe it is being written to a file or pipe. Who knows‍♂️ It's just my experience that folks sometimes say nothing came out but they were hitting buffering problems.

Try using the real IP address you want to receive from (you can get it from ifconfig). "0.0.0.0" should be fine, but it would narrow the problem. You could even do socket.getaddrinfo("0.0.0.0", 12345) to see if anything unexpected is returned. Sometimes multiple NICs, VPNs or other virtual socket drivers can make "0.0.0.0" messy.

ok, now I'm confused.  I tried specifying the IP and it worked.  I then went back and tried 0.0.0.0 again and it also worked.  There are multiple NICs

"Sorry, I hand typed the code, its an integer in my code".  FYI: don't do that.  Make a tested example on your system, and copy/paste into SO.  We don't want to see code you hand-typed and didn't test that doesn't reproduce the described issue.  It wastes our time and yours.

@MarkTolonen Love your profile "picture" - will try not to steal it

@MarkSetchell You're only the 2nd person to comment on it in years.

FYI, it's not always possible/permitted to copy/paste/download from a system or after hand copying to reproduce the exact settings of the systems of unknown setup that I have.  Yes, I could have tried running it in python to check for syntax typos.  On the other hand, running the code yourself has little value as I already stated it works on other systems or run as root.

I suspect @Barmar knows the answer if he reads your comment starting ""ok now I am confused..."

I did try -u and it didn't work when I tried.  It works now of course.  It's a good option to know now. I've run into buffering issues with other projects where this would have helped.  I remember making all sorts of queues to ensure everything came out in the right order
